# Dynamic adjustment equations coefficients using VECM from statsmodels

Tags: vector-autoregression, statsmodels, vector-error-correction-model

I am looking to replicate a study that was conducted on running a VECM to assess the short- and long-term impacts of media on sales and brand health metrics (consideration & awareness).

Using `statsmodels` I am able to run all of the appropriate checks before running calling the `VECM` class. My question here is about the VECM results that `statsmodels` displays. I know it gives us the estimated C-matrix, but wanted to know if the results also give us the adjustment equation coefficients as well? What I am looking for is in the below image for reference.

Would these be the `beta` coefs from in VECM results?

I could be missing something here since I just begun my VAR / VECM learning journey.

[image]